# LESS css "transform" syntax | on-the-fly scaling with LESS css?

Tags: html, css, less, css-transforms

What is the proper syntax for the css "transform" property in preprocessor LESS? The following, for example, throws me an error:

```
.transform(scale(1.1)) {
    -webkit-transform: @transform;
    -moz-transform: @transform;
    -ms-transform: @trasnform;
    -o-transform: @transform;
    transform: @transform; 

}
```

The error: variable "transform" is not defined.  If transform doesn't work for scaling in less css, is there an alternative?

http://less2css.org/

Edit: changed title, and asked a related, more pertinent question:

How can I specify on-the-fly scaling using only less css and hovers?

Comment: Well, in LESS you use `@identifier` for a variable identifier name. If you didn't define a variable `@transform`, then you can't use it. If you did define `@transform`, then tell us how you did so because in that case you likely shouldn't be receiving that error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `@transform` variable is never defined:

```
.transform(@transform) {
    -webkit-transform: @transform;
    -moz-transform: @transform;
    -ms-transform: @transform; /* note that you have @trasnform here */
    -o-transform: @transform;
    transform: @transform; 

}

.foo {
  .transform(scale(1.1));
}
```

Comment: Oh, ok. And alternatively, I could have done something like .transform(@scale: 1.1) { transform: @scale; }

Comment: Sure, you could do it like that as well.

Comment: Rather, .transform(@scale: 1.1) { transform: scale(@scale); }